# Can map function in JS do multiple transformations at once?

Tags: javascript, map-function

I wonder whether a map-function in JavaScript can do more than one transformation to an array at once.

For instance, can the items of an array be transformed to be doubled AND then to be divided by 3?

Thank you

Comment: The callback function you pass to `.map()` can do anything you want it to do. It can turn numbers into days of the week or names of movie stars.

Comment: The callback you will provide will have an *item* as argument. That is each element of the processed array. Then you return whaterver you like from it to create a new array. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: You mean something like `let array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];` and `array=array.map(x => x * 2 / 3);`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make multiple transformations to an array element at once all you have to do is use parenthesis to separate and have them be done in a certain order.

For your example, you could do it like this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array.map(num => (num * 2) / 3);
```

Which would give you

```
[0.6666666666666666, 1.3333333333333333, 2, 2.6666666666666665]
```